# (Android) How to detect the press of the virtual back button, home button and overview button

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I wondered how to detect the press of Android's virtual back button, home button, and overview button. For "virtual", I mean the **3-button navigation** on Android, which can be illustrated by the blue area in the screenshot. I used onKeyEvent method at my AccessibilityService and this method can successfully detect the press of all the buttons in the read area of the screenshot. However, it failed to detect the press of the buttons in the blue area. Is there any way we can also detect the press of buttons in the blue area?

Physical Buttons and Virtual Buttons

[image: 1]

Comment: Those are not "Android's virtual back button, home button, and overview button". They are controls supplied by an emulator. Whether those will be surfaced in a way that an `AccessibilityService` can use will depend on the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah the `viewResourceId` of these buttons are :

- Home: `com.android.systemui:id/home_button`
- Back: `com.android.systemui:id/back`
- Recent Apps: `com.android.systemui:id/recent_apps`

So in your onAccessibilityEvent you might do the following

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    if (accessibilityEvent.getSource() != null){
        if (accessibilityEvent.getSource().getViewIdResourceName().equals("any of the values given above as home...."){
            //Do your stuff
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with accepted answer. I had to add flag [**flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo#FLAG_RETRIEVE_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWS). Then it worked.

My whole xml

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagRequestFilterKeyEvents|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows"
    android:canPerformGestures="true"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true" />
```